# Was this Simpsons - Boy Scout link intentional?

Tags: reference, the-simpsons

Someone posted Canyonero gif from The Simpsons, in our office chat recently. I noticed the signwriting on the side of the scout's bus.

https://c.tenor.com/j3Et7zLSG1cAAAAd/canyonero-arrow.gif   (too big to upload)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lize.jpg

A screenshot of the school bus clearly shows "SCOUT TROOP 137" on the side

[image]

Some googling on that returned news reports from the 1970s.

Warning - may contain triggers for child abuse:

> The (four) men (...) decided in 1974 to found a Boy Scout unit, Troop 137 in eastern New Orleans, in order to "provide them with boys ... for their sexual pleasure," Sialle later testified. 
>  (...) 
>  Troop 137, authorities learned, "was the nucleus of a nationwide sex and pornography ring, with boys recruited into the troop sent to other states for the pleasure of the men there," according to a Times-Picayune report on the trials.
>  
>      From https://www.nola.com/news/crime_police/article_39a80521-a27b-5308-a0b6-0c195902632b.html

Links: No references to the case was found after searching.

- https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSimpsons/comments/n6bsyp/its_the_top_of_the_line_in_utility_sports/
- https://simpsons.fandom.com/wiki/Canyonero
- https://simpsonswiki.com/wiki/Canyonero
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Temptation_of_Krust and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marge_Simpson_in:_%22Screaming_Yellow_Honkers%22

Was this an intentional reference or merely a number chosen out of the air?   I can't see a mostly family-friendly show making any intentional reference to such an event.

Comment: While it certainly met FCC “safe harbor” requirements for prime time broadcast, the Simpsons in that era often pushed the boundaries of what they could get past the network censors and did not court a “family friendly” image. Examples of risqué content include references to _A Clockwork Orange_, slipping the term “Hershey Highway” into dialog, and pretty much any scene with Moe in it.